# passing list of strings to map_async()

Tags: python, python-3.x, multiprocessing

I'm having a funny issue with map_async that i can't figure out.

I'm using python's multiprocessing library with process pools. I'm trying to pass a list of strings to compare against and a list of strings to be compared to a function using map_async()

right now i have:

```
from multiprocessing import Pool, cpu_count
import functools

dictionary = /a/file/on/my/disk
passin = /another/file/on/my/disk

num_proc = cpu_count()

dictionary = readFiletoList(fdict)
dictionary = sortByLength(dictionary)

words = readFiletoList(passin, 'WINDOWS-1252')
words = sortByLength(words)

result = pool.map_async(functools.partial(mpmine, dictionary=dictionary), [words], 1000)

def readFiletoList(fname, fencode='utf-8'):
  linelist = list()
  with open(fname, encoding=fencode) as f:
    for line in f:
      linelist.append(line.strip())
  return linelist


def sortByLength(words):
  '''Takes an ordered iterable and sorts it based on word length'''
  return sorted(words, key=len)

def mpmine(word, dictionary):
  '''Takes a tuple of length 2 with it's arguments.

  At least dictionary needs to be sorted by word length. If not, whacky results ensue.
  '''
  results = dict()
  for pw in word:
    pwlen = len(pw)
    pwres = list()
    for word in dictionary:
      if len(word) > pwlen:
        break
      if word in pw:
        pwres.append(word)
    if len(pwres) > 0:
      results[pw] = pwres
  return results



if __name__ == '__main__':
  main()
```

Both dictionary and words are lists of strings. This results in only one process being used instead of the amount I have set. If i take the square brackets off the variable 'words' it seems to iterate through each string's characters in turn and cause a mess.

What i would like to have happen is it take like 1000 strings out of words and pass them into the worker process and then get the results, because this is a ridiculously parallelisable task.

EDIT: Added more code to make what's going on more clear.

Comment: You should probably give more of the code. As now we would have to add a lot to replicate the problem.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Ok, i actually figured this one out myself. I'm only going to post the answer here for anyone else who might come along and have the same issue. The reason i was having problems was because map_async takes one item from the list (in this case a string), and feeds it into the function, which was expecting a list of strings. so it then was treating each string as a list of chars basically. the corrected code for mpmine is:

```
def mpmine(word, dictionary):
  '''Takes a tuple of length 2 with it's arguments.

  At least dictionary needs to be sorted by word length. If not, whacky results ensue.
  '''
  results = dict()
  pw = word
  pwlen = len(pw)
  pwres = list()
  for word in dictionary:
    if len(word) > pwlen:
      break
    if word in pw:
      pwres.append(word)
  if len(pwres) > 0:
    results[pw] = pwres
  return results
```

I hope this helps anyone else facing a similar issue.